# How to store and retrieve values in different method c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have these two method:

1. In method1, we assign a values to ModelClass.`

   ```
    method1(ModelClass mc)
    {
        mc.name = "ABC";
        mc.contact = 123;
        mc.salary = 123.00;
        //how to store this data for use in method2 here 
    }
   ```
2. method2 is parameterised method, parameters is different from model class.

   ```
    method2(string Address, long officeContact)
    {        
        //and how to retrieve stored data from method1 to use here
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add("@name", method1.name);
        ht.Add("@contact", method1.contact);
        ht.Add("@salary ", method1.salary);

        ht.Add("@Address", Address);
        ht.Add("@officeContact", officeContact);
   }
   ```

How to use multiple values from method1 to method2. Sample code will help to understand my question.

Comment: You need to make this clearer, its unclear to me and possibly others as to what you are actually trying to achieve and what the problem is

Comment: i want to get method1 data(which i assigned in method1) into method2.

Comment: There are several compiler errors in this code. the first these methods have no return types, secondly you are calling method1 like a property when its a method. Just call method1 in method2, when you do that, what problem are you facing ?

Comment: If the goal is to have data that's assigned in method1 be accessible in method2, is it possible that both methods are part of the same class - that perhaps can store a copy of the ModelClass passed in method1 in the class's property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `method1` is setting properties of the object you're passing in.

In order to further modify the instance of `ModelClass` you either need to add another parameter to `method2` of type `ModelClass`:

`method2(string Address, long officeContact, ModelClass mc)...`

OR

The ModelClass instance used in `method1` needs to be at a scope where `method2` can see it. Like this:

```
void SomeMainMethod()
{
   var mainClass = new MainClass();
   method1(mainClass);
   method2("some address", 1);
}
```

Revised `method2`

```
 method2(string Address, long officeContact)
 {        
     //and how to retrieve stored data from method1 to use here
     Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
     ht.Add("@name", mainClass.name);
     ht.Add("@contact", mainClass.contact);
     ht.Add("@salary ", mainClass.salary);

     ht.Add("@Address", Address);
     ht.Add("@officeContact", officeContact);
}
```

Comment: revised method2, giving null value. Because im using json for input value(used in ModelClass). so i only option to get data from method1, im using session but this is also give error.

Comment: Can't help you further. This is really basic stuff.